# Silverstripe 3 create a decorator for TreeDropDownField so that I can overload the tree function

Tags: php, silverstripe

In Silverstripe 3 we are having trouble creating a decorator for TreeDropDownField so that we can overload the tree function and hide page types from the list.

We have created:

```
<?php

class TreeDropdownFieldDecorator extends Extension {

    public function tree(SS_HTTPRequest $request) { ...
```

And in _config/config.yml:

```
TreeDropdownField:
 extensions:
   - TreeDropdownFieldDecorator
```

However we aren't actually getting our tree function to get called instead of the original one.  Is this extendable in a decorator and if not, is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you’re misusing extensions. They don’t overload methods the way that subclasses do. They inject new methods into existing classes, and the core class can also invoke ->extend(‘someMethod’); to offer you a hook to modify native methods at run time, e.g. “updateCMSFields”, but in terms of purely overloading the method, that can only be done by a subclass.

Two options:

1) Use any number of the hooks that TreeDropdownField offers you. (setFilterFunction() looks like the best candidate to me... accepts an arbitrary callback), but there's also things like setChildrenMethod() and others.

2) Use the Injector to create your own TreeDropdownField.

```
Injector:
  TreeDropdownField:
    class: MyTreeDropdownFieldSubclass
```

And in your FieldList:

```
TreeDropdownField::create(...);
```

Note that the new class will not be injected if you simply use the "new" operator.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response UncleCheese!  To clarify, we are not trying to create a custom call to TreeDropdownField, rather we need to change the behavior of what gets populated in the page list throughout the default cms (as in the TreeDropdownField shown for “Under another page” when creating a new page).  We are attempting to hide pages from the list that users with a certain permission level aren't allowed to see even in lists.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. For that, you'll need to extend CMSPageAddController. http://sspaste.com/paste/show/544ac774f2f1f. For any other occurrences of TreeDropdownField, you'll have to do something similar, but this is the big one, AFAIK.